# cbs all access on firefox for ubuntu

Tags: firefox

I have not been able to watch CBS all access for some time now. Error 2004. I have not found another browser for ubuntu that will play all access either. However firefox for windows plays it fine? Is there a fix in the works for ubuntu firefox?

Comment: There's the same problem for CBS on Chrome and Opera web browsers.

Comment: It could be possible You do not have "Play DRM-controlled content" enabled in Firefox preferences. Widevine firefox plugin. Or maybe something to do with ubuntu Restricted formats/Flash. Just some suggestions to look into. I would hate for anyone to miss Star Trek Discovery or the new Picard

Comment: I noticed they not only block the show to Linux but they show you a commercial before they block the show. I guess I will be canceling my subscription. Too bad because they offer a no commercial tv I feel that should be rewarded

Comment: See https://www.howtogeek.com/114937/htg-explains-whats-a-browser-user-agent/

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, CBS has made a change on their end that now blocks Linux users. Currently, there are only two options:

1. You can subscribe to CBS All Access through Amazon Prime (I have not personally tried this)
2. Or you can use a Windows/Mac OS to watch CBS programs.

Personally though, I would suggest you simply cancel your service and tell them it's because they've blocked you.

#### References:

1. Quoted from the email I received from CBS support:

   > Looking at your viewing activity, we see that you are using a computer running the Linux operating system. Please be advised that we do not currently support this operating system.

   A few other threads can be found online from people who were able to watch from Linux and are now unable.
2. [Reddit comment of a Linux user watching via Prime](https://old.reddit.com/r/CBS/comments/elcflh/cbs_all_access_suddenly_not_working_on_linux/ff26gzp/) ([Archived link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200126001519/https://old.reddit.com/r/CBS/comments/elcflh/cbs_all_access_suddenly_not_working_on_linux/ff26gzp/))
3. [List of requirements to watch CBS in your browser](https://cbsi.secure.force.com/CBSi/articles/FAQ/What-are-the-minimum-system-requirements-for-CBS-All-Access?retURL=%2FCBSi%2Fapex%2FKnowledgeHome&popup=false&faqTitle=What+are+the+minimum+system+requirements+for+CBS+All+Access%3F&referer=cbs.com%2Faa&template=template_aa17) ([Archived link](https://archive.is/l53wV))

Answer (score 2):

CBS has got it working again all is good in Star Trek Picard land